# Iterate Foregin key options and assign it to each row in inlineformset

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have an inline formset where I need to assign the values of a ForeignKey field sequencially and univocally to each row of the inline formset. With the select default widget of a modelchoicefield everything works but I do not want the user to select any options but to be provided with a list of the options available in the foreignfield.
My inlineformset is the following:

```
class ResultadoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    frequencia = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    tolerancia = forms.CharField(max_length=255)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        equipamento_id = kwargs.pop('equipamento_id', None)
        super (ResultadoForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['teste'].queryset = Teste.objects.filter(equipamento=equipamento_id).order_by('grupoteste', 'numeracao')

    class Meta:
        model = Resultado
        exclude = ['actividade']
```

My view that renders the form:

```
@login_required()
def QAView(request, equipamento_id):

    form = ActividadeForm()
    form1 = ResultadoForm(equipamento_id)
    equipamento = Equipamento.objects.get(id=equipamento_id)
    testes_list = Teste.objects.filter(equipamento=equipamento_id)
    FormSet = inlineformset_factory(Actividade, Resultado, form=ResultadoForm, fields='__all__', extra=len(testes_list))
    formset = FormSet(form_kwargs={'equipamento_id': equipamento_id})
    context = {'equipamento_id': equipamento_id, 'data':datetime.now(), 'equipamento': equipamento, 'form': form, 'testes_list': testes_list, 'formset': formset}
    template = 'SFM/Equipamento/QA.html'

return render(request, template, context)
```

And in my template:

```
{% for r in formset %}
{{ r.id }}
{% for t in r.teste.field.queryset %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ t}}</td>
        <td>{{ t.frequencia }}</td>
        <td>{{ t.tolerancia }}</td>
        <td>{{ r.conforme }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

My Resultado Model:

```
class Resultado(models.Model):
    CONFORME_CHOICES = (
    ("Sim", "Sim"),
    ("Não", "Não"),
    )

    teste = models.ForeignKey(Teste, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    conforme = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=CONFORME_CHOICES)
    actividade = models.ForeignKey(Actividade, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
    return str(self.id)
```

With this template I get 4 rows. I should only get two. But I have two foreign key options so I am getting the two foreign options repeated.
Is it possible to assign one and only one foreign key to each row of this inlineformset? For example for the first row automatically assign the first foreign value and to the second row the second foreign value. Please help.

Comment: Can you give the structure of the Resultado model as well?

Comment: Just a thought, but perhaps if you specified `fields = ['...']` in the Meta, you could control the output better

Comment: @Nez Updated the question with Resultado Model

Comment: Thanks. It helps me think about what's going on a bit. Have you tried explicitly declaring `fields = `?

Comment: Yes I did but I still get the same behavior...